# Generate Private Key From PEM File

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to install an SSL Certificate on my website, I bought the certificate online but they didn't give me a private key file, I got a pem file instead. Is their any way I can generate the private key file from the pem file?

I'm using a Mac and tried OpenSSL to generate the key file:

```
openssl rsa -in myfile.pem -out private.key
```

But this gave me the following error:

```
unable to load Private Key
4781944428:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:684:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As the private key has to be private could you kindly share just the beginning of your pem-file ("------BEGIN..." so see what kind of pem-file we are talking? Did you receive any password for the key?

Comment: @MichaelFehr Hi, sure, it starts with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----". No, I didn't receive a password, but I can ask for it.

Comment: I'm not the specialist in SSL certificates but usually you generate your own key pair (so YOU own the private key), next generate a certificate request (".csr-file") and send it to the certification agency ("ca"). They sign your request with their private key and send you the signed certificate back to you - that is the "--- begin certificate..."-file you already have now). This certificate will be used with your webserver and is the proove for the httpS-connection. The private key is still in your environment and can be used with your server credentials. The cert has NO private key included.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the private key is generated on your web server through the web server software or else using openssl.

When you buy a certificate online from a certificate authority, you generate a certificate request, and send it to the authority. The cert request doesn't have the private key, only a signature from the private key, so that's why you can't extract it from the pem file they sent you back.

You need to look at the software you used to generate the certificate request. If you didn't do this, and the company you bought the cert didn't require it, they may be a hosting provider who has the private keys.